# Django template naming with dashes VS underscores

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, naming-conventions

We are using the Django framework and in the book "2 scoops of django" there is a recommendation to use underscore naming for specific things, should this be included in the naming of templates as well? front end developers here are really locked on dashes and I was just wondering?

Answer (score 9):

I think one reason why underscores are better in Python files is so that they can be imported. A dash is interpreted as a minus sign, which can cause problems.

For your Django templates, it's a matter of preference so you will likely be fine using any convention you prefer.